# Areca Palm's leaves are drying. What should I do?

Tags: watering, indoors, palm, dryness

I bought a small areca palm 3 months ago.

[image: My palm]

I noticed some leaves are drying out and dying. The others is drying as well.

[image: The leaves are drying and dying]
[image: The surviving leaves are continuing dry out]

My palm is indoors in the apartment's lobby. The temperature inside is around 20-25 degree Celsius. The palm is sitting in low sunlight spot. I water it every 4 or 5 days or even a week. I don't use fertilizer, feed or anything else.

Could anyone please help me to know what to do to save it?

Answer (score 1):

It probably wants some more light and less watering. Put it some where near a window where it gets direct sunlight. Water it about once a week or whenever the top 1-2 inches of soil are dry to the touch.